# 3 "Dimensional" array in JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I miss VB. Maybe that's sad...

I need to make a "3 Dimensional" array to represent the following data. The data begins as XML and gets parsed into a 2D "Array of arrays" as follows (descriptors added for clarity):

```
[NodeArray]
    [Node: 0][Year: 2012][Quantity1: 3][Quantity2: 5] [Title: Orange]
    [Node: 1][Year: 2012][Quantity1: 5][Quantity2: 9] [Title: Apple]
    [Node: 2][Year: 2011][Quantity1: 4][Quantity2: 9] [Title: Orange]
    [Node: 3][Year: 2011][Quantity1: 8][Quantity2: 12] [Title: Apple]
    [Node: 4][Year: 2010][Quantity1: 2][Quantity2: 6] [Title: Orange]
    [Node: 5][Year: 2010][Quantity1: 10][Quantity2: 2] [Title: Apple]
```

I want to parse this 2-D Array into a 3-D Object Array as follows:

```
[Year Array]
    [2012]
        [Quantity1]: [3],[7]
        [Quantity2]: [5],[9]
        [Title]: [Orange],[Apple]
    [2011]
        [Quantity1]: [4],[8]
        [Quantity2]: [9],[12]
        [Title]: [Orange],[Apple]
    [2010]
        [Quantity1]: [2],[10]
        [Quantity2]: [6],[2]
        [Title]: [Orange],[Apple]
```

In VB this would have been pretty simple. I would have looked at my original data and redimensioned my array to accomodate the maximum number of entries in each dimension. I would then iterate through the data and load it in...

If the 2012 index = 0 then "Array(0,1,1)" would have returned "9"

I believe this can be done in JSON, but I don't have enough experience to know how. I hope this question is specific enough to provide some insight on what I am trying to accomplish.

**------------------EDIT & NEW CODE-----------------**

I appreciate the answers.

I realize that my fatal flaw at the moment is that I am not building my 2-D array using JSON (despite the fact that my example seems that way). Here is the method I am using to build my 2-D Array:

```
for(i=0; i<titleArray.length; i++)
{
rowArray[i] = [yearArray[i], titleArray[i],quantityOneArray[i],quantityTwoArray[i]];
}
```

Because there are always the same number of entries in each array I can reliably use the length of one array to iterate through all associated arrays. I also realize that using "i++" is the middle school way of doing things, so I am open to suggestions on more elegant indexing methods.

But let's say I want to build this in JSON? I am confident that this is not yet in a JSON format... If it were then I should be able to say "rowArray[i].year" yes?

Thanks again - I am very fortunate to have such an active community.

**--------------------EDIT2 & NEW CODE--------------------**

Ok, I think I cracked the JSON nut. I likey! I only had to format the array object a little differently and now I can invoke members of the array by using the .whatever property!

```
for(i=0; i<titleArray.length; i++) 
{
rowArray[i] = {"year":yearArray[i], "title":titleArray[i],"quantity1":quantityOneArray[i],"quantity2":quantityTwoArray[i]};
console.log("rowArray["+i+"]: " + rowArray[i].year + ", " + rowArray[i].title +", "+rowArray[i].quantity1+", "+rowArray[i].quantity2);
}
```

Now for the 3-D Array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var year_array = new Array(); // empty array
for ( node in node_array )
{
    if ( !year_array.hasOwnProperty(node.year) ) // if year is not in array yet
    {
        year_array[node.year] = new Array(); // create an empty array for it
    }
    year_array[node.year].push({
        "quantity1": node.quantity1,
        "quantity2": node.quantity2,
        "title": node.title,
    });
}
```

All this does is go through the 2D array, and puts the values in the 3D array in the format presented. The only bit that's tricky is the `if ( !year_array.hasOwnProperty(node.year) )` block, which initializes each year's entry the first time it comes up.

Comment: This looks like the ticket... I also realize that I am building my array incorrectly to utilize your code. I will add my routine in an edit above.

Comment: Ok - getting an unexpected syntax error; hopefully I can get the sample code in here ok:  `yearArray = {}; for(i=0; i<rowArray.length; i++){ if(!yearArray.hasownProperty(rowArray[i].year){ yearArray[rowArray[i].year]={}; Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ } yearArray[rowArray[i].year].quantity1+=rowArray[i].quantity1; yearArray[rowArray[i].year].quantity2+=rowArray[i].quantity2; yearArray[rowArray[i].year].title+=rowArray[i].title; }`  Note the unexpected token error. I don't believe I am allowed to index this way...

Comment: @Chris: Try changing `yearArray = {};` to `var yearArray = new Array();`.

Comment: Hmmm no change. I tried `yearArray = new Array()` and `yearArray = []`. My gut instinct is that I can't use `rowArray[i].year` as an index value for the `yearArray` object. Let's see if I try it a different way...

Comment: Meh, I made a typo; note the lack of a closing paren on the `if(!yearArray.hasownProperty(rowArray[i].year){ ` statment. One more bug further down and then I'll see what I get!

Comment: Your code worked like a champ - only ONE caveat!! I need to build an array of "quantity1" and "quantity2" and "title" inside of "yearArray". This line ultimately returns a "NaN" not an array: `yearArray[rowArray[i].year].quantity2+=rowArray[i].quantity2;` If I take away the `+=` then it makes a great 3D arry, but only 1 entry a piece in the third dimension. Is there an append command that I should be using?

Comment: @Chris: `NaN` is "Not a Number." That line shouldn't be returning anything; it's setting `yearArray[...].quantity2` to itself plus `rowArray[i].quantity2`. Are you sure that all of the `quantity2`s in `rowArray` are numbers?

Comment: Here is [a screenshot of my chrome console](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v34/Shrout1/3DJSONArrays.png) with the objects side-by side

Comment: I _think_ that by using += it is trying to evaluate the strings mathematically? This is leading to a "NaN". If I leave the code as `yearArray[rowArray[i].year].quantity2=rowArray[i].quantity2` then it returns objects like the "good" one on the right in that Chrome screenshot, except that they only have one entry in the 3rd dimension instead of multiple. I.E. there is only a single "quantity1" for 2012 even though there should be 2.

Comment: @Chris: Oh duh. Yeah, I forgot to actually create the third dimension even though I set everything up to do it. Now each year is properly an array, each with `quantity1`, `quantity2`, and `title`, instead of overwriting itself.

Comment: Well, I think I at least partially solved it - thank you for all your help Dragoon! `yearArray[rowArray[i].year].quantity1+= ", " + rowArray[i].quantity1;` I believe that maintains the JSON format while keeping everything as a string. I need to try referencing it, but I think your answer solved my problem! Wish I could spot you some extra rep for all your help; soon enough!

Comment: I will play with the push command as well :) Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 3):

The data as a JSON object would look like

```
var data = 
{
    "2011": {
        "Quantity1": [ 3, 7],
        "Quantity2": [ 5, 9],
        "Title": [
            "Orange",
            "Apple"
        ]
    },
    "2012": {
        "Quantity1": [ 4, 8],
        "Quantity2": [ 9, 12],
        "Title": [
            "Orange",
            "Apple"
        ]
    }, 
    ...
}
```

Notice I'm using an object for the first 2 levels of the structure, this is so you can index them with string. e.g, your `Array(0,1,1)` would become `data["2011"]["Quantity2"][1]`.

Alternatively you could use array and have

```
var data = 
[
    [
        [ 3, 7],
        [ 5, 9],
        [ "Orange",
          "Apple" ]
    ],
    [
        [ 4, 8],
        [ 9, 12],
        [ "Orange",
            "Apple" ]
    ], 
    ...
]
```

You could then do `data[0][1][1]` which is a lot like your VB example.